# Своя система кэширования. Что читать?

Tags: кэширование

Появилась необходимость создать свою систему кэширования (типа Meamecache).
Не знаю куда смотреть, что искать. Подскажите ключевые слова для поиска.

Comment: для чего? слова, кэш, мемкэш, как написать?

Comment: @Gorets для каждого проекта нужен свой механизм.

Comment: @Вадим Шушляков Для сколачивания каждого ящика свой молоток? Или "пусть хреновое, но своё"?

Comment: @Вадим Шушляков, "создание собственной системы кэширования. урок для чайников, нубов..."

Answer (score 1):

Доброго время суток. Могу дать подбор ссылок чуть более глубокого понимания механизма кэширование (не поверхностного), а именно инвалидация кэша по событию через принцип тегирования кэша.
Как мы знаем, существую два способа инвалидации кэша (сделать оный тухлым):

- по времени;
- по событию (к примеру, произошли некие изменения в БД, через админку, front-end или как-то иначе)

Оба этих способа можно и совмещать.

Собственно, вот перечень ссылок на материал по тегированию кэша.

http://dklab.ru/chicken/nablas/47.html

http://tokarchuk.ru/2012/07/tagging-in-memory-cache/

http://habrahabr.ru/post/43539/

http://habrahabr.ru/post/159079/

Как правило в большинстве известных фреймворках решение подобной задачи имеется, но иногда недостаточно.

**P.S.** В моём проекте тегирование осуществляется по названию сущностей (таблиц БД). Осуществляется проверка принадлежности данного ресурса (записи) к конкретной таблице. Правда, ещё буду думать над структурой тегирования на предмет уменьшения разброса.

Comment: Вы немного не правильно поняли вопрос. Я знаю как работать с Meamcache. Мне нужно сделать как бы сам Meamcache.

Comment: @Вадим Шушляков, а что мешает взять сам мемкэш, и модифицировать его под свои нужды?

Answer (score 1):

[Caching in theory and practice -- неплохая статья про стратегии кэширования в dropbox tech blog](https://tech.dropbox.com/2012/10/caching-in-theory-and-practice/)